# Bugzilla templates: what's the difference between [% and [%+

Tags: syntax, bugzilla, template-toolkit

Code in Bugzilla templates is usually delimited by [% and %].  But sometimes I see [%+ and [%-.  Can someone explain the difference or point me at suitable documentation?  Google has failed me on this occasion.

For example:

```
[%- event.value.subject FILTER html %]
```

or

```
[%+ END %]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[%-` (or `-%]`) removes leading (trailing) whitespace; `[%+` (or `+%]`) maintains it. See [PRE_CHOMP, POST_CHOMP](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_PRE_CHOMP_POST_CHOMP) in the Template Toolkit Manual (Bugzilla templates use the Template Toolkit) for the gory details (including `[=` and `[~` :)).

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I wrote for our team last year:

I was less informed about TT's behavior than I should have been, and another member of our team has confessed to me that he was even less informed than I was!

This is a brief explanation of how chomping works.

Suppose I have the following template, with the variable x = 'foo'

```
<td>
  [% x %]
</td>
```

will become

```
<td>
  foo
</td>
```

Note the spaces at the beginning of the second line.

TT has configuration settings for PRE_CHOMP and POST_CHOMP.

If PRE_CHOMP is 1, then all the whitespace in front of a directive, including a newline, is removed.  The example becomes

```
<td>foo
</td>
```

If POST_CHOMP is 1, then the opposite occurs on the other end:

```
<td>
foo</td>
```

If PRE/POST_CHOMP is 2, then all preceding/succeeding whitespace is collapsed to a single space:

```
<td> foo </td>
```

If PRE/POST_CHOMP is 3, then all preceding/succeeding whitespace is eliminated:

```
<td>foo</td>
```

==IMPORTANT==

Bugzilla is configured with PRE_CHOMP = 1.  POST_CHOMP is not set.

You can explicitly denote chomping behavior with one of the characters -, =, ~, and + after the '[%' or before the '%]'. '-' denotes CHOMP level 1, = denotes CHOMP level 2, ~ denotes CHOMP level 3, + denotes no chomping regardless of whether it is set in the overall configuration.

So to repeat the example:

```
<td>
  [% x %]
</td>
```

Because we have PRE_CHOMP = 1, then this will become

```
<td>foo
</td>

<td>
[%- x -%]
<td>
```

becomes

```
<td>foo</td>

<td>
[%= x =%]
</td>
```

becomes `<td> foo </td>`

```
<td>

[%~ x ~%]

</td>
```

becomes `<td>foo</td>`

Finally,

```
<td>
  [%+ x %]
</td>
```

becomes

```
<td>
  foo
</td>
```

For an even more verbose explanation, do 'perldoc Template::Manual::Config' and search for CHOMP.